# TypeScript model and API response data diff checker report

Tags: javascript, typescript

### The problem

As a Front-end developer, I do not have control over the data that is returned from the Backend. I sometimes notice that the data shape and types I expect on the Front-end are different from the actual data inside the API response. I don't want to manually look up these differences and I want to have some kind of report that points out these cases:

**1. Missing Property** - some properties that I expect are not found inside the response data

**2. Unexpected Property** - extra properties inside the response data that I don't expect

**3. Type Mismatch** - the types on certain properties inside the response data are different from what I expect

**4. Nullable Mismatch** - I don't expect the value on certain properties to be *null*

Based on this, I'm trying to create `apiDiffCheckReport`, that generates the mentioned report and checks whether `res.data` is safe to dump inside my typed `users` array. So I can simply do this after every API GET response:

```
const res = await axios.get("https://my.api.com/users") 
const [isResDataSafe, report] = apiDiffCheckReport(res.data) // <-- res.data is always type of <any>

if (isResDataSafe) {
  const users: User[] = res.data // <-- here res.data is "type of <User[]>" 
}
```

### The solution

To be more specific, I have a TypeScript User model (this is how I expect the response data to look like):

*models/User.ts*

```
export interface Comment {
  id: number;
  body: string;
}

export interface User {
  id: number;
  createdAt?: string;
  newsLetter?: boolean;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  comments?: Comment[];
}
```

and my API returns the following data after calling the `/users` endpoint:

*API Response data*

```js
[
  {
    "id": "0", // <-- Should detect this as 3. Type Mismatch,
               //     because I expect a <number> here
    "createdAt": "2020-06-06T08:34:49.749Z",
    "newsLetter": true,
    "isPremium": false, // <-- Should detect this as 2. Unexpected Property, 
                        //     because I don't expect this property
    "name": "John",
    // <-- Should detect this as 1. Missing Property, 
    //     because I expect an `age` property here
    "comments": [
      {
        "id": null, // <-- Should detect this as 4. Nullable Mismatch, 
                    //     because I don't expect <null> here
    
        "subtitle": "my first comment" // <-- Should detect this as 2. Unexpected Property, 
                                       //     because I don't expect this property

        // <-- Should detect this as 1. Missing Property, 
        //     because I expect a `body` property here
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "1",
    "createdAt": "2010-06-06T08:34:49.749Z",
    "newsLetter": false,
    "isPremium": false,
    "name": "Tom",
    "comments": [
      {
        "id": null,
        "subtitle": "my second comment"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

First, I flat (using *npm flat*) the API response data and my initialized expected *User array*. To my *User array* values I also hardcode the information whether the property is nullable or not like so:

*data/UserDataManager.ts*

```
const flatResData = flat(resData); 
const flatExpectedData = flat(initUserArr(resData.length));
const flatExpectedAllData = initAllUserArr(flatResData, flatExpectedData);

// console.log(flatResData)
// {
// 0.id: "0"
// 0.createdAt: "2020-06-06T08:34:49.749Z"
// 0.newsLetter: true
// 0.isPremium: false
// 0.name: "John"
// 0.comments.0.id: null
// 0.comments.0.subtitle: "my first comment"
// 1.id: "1"
// 1.createdAt: "2010-06-06T08:34:49.749Z"
// 1.newsLetter: false
// 1.isPremium: false
// 1.name: "Tom"
// 1.comments.0.id: null
// 1.comments.0.subtitle: "my second comment" }

// console.log(flatExpectedAllData)
// {
// 0.id: 1                     <-- not nullable
// 0.age: 1                    <-- not nullable
// 0.name: "1"                 <-- not nullable
// 0.createdAt: "0"            <-- nullable
// 0.newsLetter: false         <-- nullable
// 0.comments.0.id: 1              and so on...
// 0.comments.0.body: "1"
// 1.id: 1
// 1.age: 1
// 1.name: "1"
// 1.createdAt: "0"
// 1.newsLetter: false
// 1.comments.0.id: 1
// 1.comments.0.body: "1" }
```

Inside my `apiDiffCheckReport`, I'm handling each report's case separately. To get the **1. Missing Properties** and the **2. Unexpected Properties**, I first look for all the matching keys (`subKeys` for arrays i.e. `0.comments`) in both `resDataKeys` and `flatExpectedKeys`. After that I just simply filter out all the extra keys from the original array:

```
const matchingKeys = flatExpectedKeys.map(key => {
  let matchingKey = "";

  if (flatResKeys.includes(key)) {
    matchingKey = key;
  }

  const subKey = getSubKey(key);

  if (flatResKeys.includes(subKey)) {
    matchingKey = subKey;
  }

  return matchingKey;
});

// for 1. Missing Properties the `targetArr` is `flatExpectedKeys`. In other words, give me all the keys
// that were expected but were not found inside `flatResKeys`.

// for 2. Unexpected Properties the `targetArr` is `flatResKeys`. In other words, give me all the keys
// that arrived inside the API response but were not found inside `flatExpectedKeys`.

return targetArr.filter(key => !matchingKeys.includes(key));
```

Finally, In both cases, I simply remove the duplicates and make the keys more human-readable. As a result, I get something like this:

```
// console.log(extractUnexpectedKeys(flatExpectedKeys, flatResKeys))
//               ↓
return formatReportKeys(arrUnique(arrNoDigits(unexpectedKeys)));
 
// [".isPremium", ".comments[].subtitle"]

// console.log(extractMissingKeys(flatExpectedKeys, flatResKeys))
//               ↓
return formatReportKeys(arrUnique(arrNoDigits(missingKeys)));

// [".age", ".comments[].body"]
```

To get the **3. Type Mismatch** report, I loop through the `expected keys`, check whether the key is also inside `response keys`, and then compare the two key-value types. I ignore the cases when the value is *null* and the property is nullable. That should not be a *Type Mismatch*, because I also expect `null` in that case:

```
const mismatchedTypes: any = [];

Object.keys(flatExpectedData).forEach(key => {
  if (Object.keys(flatResData).includes(key)) {
    const item = {
      key: key,
      expectedType: typeof flatExpectedData[key],
      foundType: typeof flatResData[key]
    };
    const isTypeMismatch = item.foundType !== item.expectedType;
    const isNullable =
      flatResData[key] === null &&
      (flatExpectedData[key] === 0 || 
        flatExpectedData[key] === "0" ||
        flatExpectedData[key] === false); // <-- this is where I make use of the User array 
                                          //     initialization, back in data/UserDataManager.ts, I'm 
                                          //     using the value to find out whether the property is 
                                          //     nullable  or not

    if (isTypeMismatch && !isNullable) {
      mismatchedTypes.push(item);
    }
  }
});
```

And finally the **4. Nullable Mismatch**, I look for a mismatch through the values again:

```
const isTypeMismatch =
  typeof flatExpectedData[key] !== typeof flatResData[key];
const isNullableMismatch =
  flatResData[key] === null &&
  (flatExpectedData[key] !== 0 &&
    flatExpectedData[key] !== "0" &&
    flatExpectedData[key] !== false);
    
if (isTypeMismatch && isNullableMismatch) {
  mismatchedNullables.push(key);
}
```

This is what the final report looks like:

```
// 0: { case: 1, key: ".age" }
// 1: { case: 1, key: ".comments[].body" }
// 2: { case: 3, key: ".id", expectedType: "number", foundType: "string" }
// 3: { case: 3, key: ".comments[].id", expectedType: "number", foundType: "object" }
// 4: { case: 4, key: ".comments[].id" }
// 5: { case: 2, key: ".isPremium" }
// 6: { case: 2, key: ".comments[].subtitle" }
```

Before I jump into my TODOS, I would like some feedback on my current progress. Feel free to edit the code on sandbox, please ignore the `generateHtmlReport`, that's just a quick way to visualize the final report.

[image: Edit new]

### TODOS

- handle nullable arrays (I'm only to identify primitive nullable types via values, but I don't know how to handle arrays/objects)
- more options inside `apiDiffCheckReport`, such as `isStrict` (allow warnings), `isFull` (all cases), etc.

Comment: I feel like this is a lot of hardwork that should be fixed backend. Why not contact the people responsible and see if it can't be fixed. If that doesn't work, I would probably create a proxy server that automatically fills in the gaps and/or filter out incomplete data.

Comment: @kemicofaghost if we are talking real-world application I agree that this is a lot of extra code to have on the Front-end. But I want to integrate this into my E2E tests and CI/CD build so this report is generated alongside my code coverage report automatically. Also, we are developing a brand new larger-scale app so the data changes quite often at the moment and the people responsible will also have this report available, so in some cases, we can resolve these inconsistencies individually.